# How to achieve a perspective effect of the human body using three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am a beginner and I would like to achieve the following effect using three.js.
I have a human body model and an internal organs model. On the webpage, the human body model is displayed. When the user selects the head with the mouse, the position of the mouse should show the brain. When the user selects the chest, the position of the mouse should show the lungs. The rest of the unselected areas should still display the human body model.
What method should be used to achieve this effect? Can you provide some guidance? Thank you~

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpNZ.png)

I have been able to load the two models normally, but I don’t know how to achieve perspective.